# Crystal Reports - export to pdf in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf, crystal-reports

I have integrated the below code in my application to generate a 'pdf' file using crystal reports in MVC project. 
However, after the request is processed, i get to see only 2 pages in the pdf file while my 'data' returns more than 2 records.
Also, the pdf isn't rendered as soon as the page is processed but instead i have to refresh atleast once, then the pdf is rendered on the browser.

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;

public FileStreamResult Report()
{
    ReportClass rptH = new ReportClass();
    List<sampledataset> data = objdb.getdataset();
    rptH.FileName = Server.MapPath("[reportName].rpt");
    rptH.Load();
    rptH.SetDatabaseLogon("un", "pwd", "server", "db");
    rptH.SetDataSource(data);
    Stream stream = rptH.ExportToStream
       (CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
    stream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");   
}
```

I took the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348785/crystal-reports-in-asp-net-mvc) in SO but modified it like above.

TIA.

**EDIT**: This works on Firefox, not in IE7.

Comment: It almost sounds like the `FileStreamResult` is not flushing. Have you tried returning a `FileResult` instead of a FileStreamResult?

Comment: @Robert Harvey - can you provide an example? I am using MVC version 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724358/ie-wont-load-pdf-in-a-window-created-with-window-open) on SO. It had nothing to do with MVC but the way IE treats popup window.